# Permanently disable broken TouchPad on HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad, hp-laptop

I have an [HP Folio13](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03166802#AbT0) laptop which includes a **Synaptics TouchPad**. I'm running Windows 7 Home.

**I want to permanently disable the TouchPad** since it doesn't function properly so I use a mouse or keyboard nav instead, but I'm constantly hitting the TouchPad with my wrist.

- In **Mouse** Settings:

  - <kbd>ClickPad Disable</kbd> indeed disables it, but only until I reboot.
  - *`Disable internal pointing device when mouse is plugged in`* doesn't help me when the mouse is *not* plugged in.
- In **Device Manager**:

  - the context menu doesn't have a `Disable` option like other devices.
  - If I `Uninstall` the driver, it auto-reinstall soon after.
- I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/928385/774713) but the fixes are specific to Dell so,

  - I don't see an option in BIOS, and,
  - I don't have the option to disable in the Mobility Centre.

Surely I'm missing an option somewhere, to avoid having to open up the laptop and physically disconnect it?

Thanks!

[image: img]

Comment: Open up the laptop. Inside you will have a molex that connects the touchpad to the keyboard. Disconnect it. Tape the end of the molex to protect against shorts. Close the laptop.

Comment: Thanks - although I was trying to avoid having to open it... One would think there'd be a software method, or at least prevent drivers from auto-reinstalling for a specific device.  (Hmm, I wonder if it would be bad for me to intentionally corrupt the DLL...)

Comment: aren't tongue in cheek comments the best? :P your approach is solid but you forgot a critical step. you need to remove the drivers from your drive store.

Comment: @RicardoS. -that wasn't actually intended as tongue-in-cheek, so I tried it, and my problem appears to be **[solved](https://superuser.com/a/1372893/774713)!** :-)

Answer (score 1):

...after I [thought](https://superuser.com/questions/1372863/permanently-disable-broken-touchpad-on-hp-laptop#comment2067234_1372863) about it more, I simply backed up the driver specific to the TouchPad (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\SynTP.sys`) and then replaced it with a random file (I just renamed a jpg.)

After rebooting, the TouchPad is completely disabled, and there doesn't appear to be any other ill-effects, plus I didn't even get an error - except, of course, when I check the Status of the driver:

[image: img]

*...ahhh,* that's better!

Comment: That's creative :) I'm afraid that Windows Update may break it, though.

Comment: Windows Update has run without a problem... maybe since this driver is from the laptop's OEM rather than Microsoft...?

Comment: It will run fine, but at some point Synaptics may release a new driver and WU will try to install it, replacing your broken driver with a real one. I don't know about Synaptics, but ELAN touchpads get WU updates a few times per year.